# Is it possible to disable cloud saves for specific games/apps?

Tags: steam

I'm planning on buying [articy:draft 3](https://store.steampowered.com/app/322330). I want to keep my projects local only and do my own backups. I don't want anything from my projects to be saved to the cloud. Is it possible to disable it for certain games and apps?

Comment: You can certainly disable it *altogether*.  That should accomplish the goal, as described.

Comment: @Steve-O Not really, seeing how I'm asking about disabling it only for certain games/apps, not for all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, but you have to do it manually for each game you want to disable Steam Cloud for. Example taken from [Gearbox Software (Borderlands 2)](https://gearboxsoftware.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205280370-PC-How-to-Disable-Steam-Cloud-Save-Game-Synchronization):

> 1. In your Steam Library, right-click on Borderlands 2 and select
>      "Properties."
> 2. Click the "Updates" tab.
> 3. Uncheck "Enable Steam
>      Cloud synchronization for Borderlands 2."
> 4. Click "Close."

So you just have to follow these guidelines, replacing "Borderlands 2" with the game you want to disable Steam Cloud for.

Screenshot from my Steam Library, showing the option.
[image]

Comment: is it stilll possible? I don't see this checkbox under "updates" in Unravel settings in the newest Steam.

Comment: it seems Unravel is a game managed by Origin (EA), so it won't have a Steam Cloud option. I checked for a game on my Steam Library, and yes it still has the option.
Link for Unravel: https://crinrict.com/blog/2016/02/everything-about-your-saves.html

Comment: hmm, but my saves were automatically transferred to the other machine. if not Steam, what would do that - Origin? thanks for checking anyway!

Comment: @Line yes, Origin does it too (that's the whole point of cloud saves btw). If you're still blocked, I recommend you start a new topic with the "origin" tag.

Comment: oh, I see :) thanks a lot